# How to obtain numeric-style citation call-outs with the 'chicago' bibliography style?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, citing, chicago-style

How to change the citation style so that I can use just number to represent the content inside the parenthesis?

[image]

Also I cannot assign number to the reference. Below is the reference, how can I add index to them?

[image]

Here is my some of my code:

1. class file: for the bibliography part

```
\RequirePackage{chicago}
\renewcommand{\refname}{\textbf{References}}
```

2. all the packages I used:

```
\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx,bm,mathtools}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf,labelsep=period]{caption}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,citecolor=black,linkcolor=black]{hyperref}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{subcaption}
```

3. at the end of the paper:

```
\bibliographystyle{chicago}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textbf{References}}
\bibliography{References}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the objective is to generate numeric-style citation call-outs while keeping the `chicago` bibliography style, you may achieve it by changing the instruction

```
\RequirePackage{chicago}
```

to

```
\usepackage[numbers,square]{natbib}
```

and perform a full recompilation cycle: LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more. This works because whereas the `chicago` citation management package can produce only authoryear-style citation call-outs, the `natbib` citation management package can produce both authoryear-style and numeric-style citation call-outs.

Let me also remark that the `chicago` bibliography style was last updated in 1992 and thus implements the bibliography-related formatting guidelines of the *13th* edition of the *Chicago Manual of Style*. If you need to implement "Chicago"'s *current* guidelines, which are based on the *17th* edition of "Chicago" (published in 2017), by far your best bet is to switch from BibTeX/natbib to biblatex/biber and to employ the [biblatex-chicago](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-chicago) package.

---

Here's a screenshot of the third page produced by a compilable document that uses the `natbib` package instead of the `chicago` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report} % or some other document class that provides a \chapter command

% create a dummy bib file:
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{References.bib}
@misc{ab:3001,
  author = "Anne Author and Brenda Buthor",
  title  = "Thoughts",
  year   = 3001,
}
\end{filecontents}

%\RequirePackage{chicago}
\usepackage[numbers,square]{natbib} % <-- new
\bibliographystyle{chicago}

\renewcommand{\bibname}{References} % change '\bibname', not '\refname'

\usepackage{mathtools} % mathtools loads amsmath automatically
\usepackage{graphicx,bm}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf,labelsep=period]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{multirow,textcomp,afterpage}
\usepackage{pdflscape,hhline,enumitem}
\usepackage[colorlinks,citecolor=black,linkcolor=black]{hyperref} 
% 'hyperref' should (generally) be loaded _last_

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage

Generate a citation callout: \cite{ab:3001}

\clearpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{References}
\bibliography{References}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It works perfect, thanks! Another weird thing is that yesterday I compiled the same code in different tex files, one file can list the reference with number, the other file doesn't have number.

Comment: @yuan - Does the file that doesn't produce numeric-style citation call-outs possibly possess more than one `\bibliographystyle` instruction? Does it maybe load some other citation management package in addition to `natbib`? Does the .blg log file report warning or error messages?